# Add scope for Google Games Services Google Client

Tags: php, google-play-services

I am following the text from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Here it is mentioned that

```
Set the scopes required for the API you are going to call

$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
```

I want to access Google Games Api

How do I add scope and access the api?

Answer (score 0):

The scope for Google Play Games as indicated in [GPGS Scopes doc](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes) is

```
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games"
```

You can see the PHP implementation in the [Type a Number PHP sample](https://github.com/playgameservices/web-basic-samples/blob/master/type-a-number-php/index.php)

```
 <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games" />
```

Read more on [Get Started with Play Games Services for Web](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/gettingstarted) for additional info.

Comment: I am implementing it server side,

Comment: scope doesn't change, read [Set Up Play Games Services for Web on the Server](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/serverlogin)